# Autodesk-Forge View Your Models Tutorial Model not uploading

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have followed the Autodesk ["View Your Models" Tutorial](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewmodels)...incredibly helpful.  I believe I have followed the tutorial, the site loads, and my existing buckets are shown with their current models listed.  However when I create a new bucket and attempt to upload a model it does not show as having arrived in the bucket (I have refreshed, and waited 12 hours).  There is a white arrow for expanding the bucket (to show its child models), but when clicked it just goes away.

The files I have attempted to upload are in the "Uploads" folders. Models I had in already existing buckets load and can be viewed.

I receive the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/node start.js 
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1360:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1401:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1485:7)
    at Function.listen (/Users/ben/Documents/GitHub/sampleForgeNode/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ben/Documents/GitHub/sampleForgeNode/start.js:21:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

[image]

Comment: The error you included doesn't seem to be related to a problem with uploading files to buckets. That `EADDRINUSE` typically happens when you try to start a server on certain port when there's another server already running and using the port. Can you double-check if there are any other error logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad you enjoyed the tutorial! :-)

About the error, `EADDRINUSE` usually indicates the port (e.g. `3000`) is already in use by another process. In most cases, it's another nodejs sample you left running or stopped working. On Windows, open the Task Manager and end all nodejs processes. For MacOS, open the Activity Monitor and kill all nodejs processes.

From your description, I would say that the upload is failing and, after that, a Nodejs process remains running and causing the `EADDRINUSE` error. As mentioned by **Petr Broz**, please check the terminal console for any error message that can identify the problem (probably during upload). You may try with a small file to get started, big files can cause timeout errors.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification regarding the error.  I uploaded smaller .dwg and .rvt models successfully.  Is there a way to adjust the timeout?

Comment: the timeout depends on your connection too, you may adjust on your end, but even that can fail if the file is too big or the connection breaks... better to go with resumable ;)